# Tinymce paste problem in google chrome

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using following javascript code to convert double `<br>` into paragraph.

```
paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
   o.content = o.content.replace(/\<br\>\<br\>/gi, '</p><p>');
   o.content = '<p>'+o.content+'</p>';
},
```

This code works fine for firefox when I copy text from notepad and paste it but in Google chrome it adds `<p> </p>` on top and bottom and instead of `<p>` i see one `<pre>` tag and double `<br>` here is the sample output

```
<p> </p>
<pre>http://www.google.com/support<br /><br />visit Google.com for more information</pre>
<p> </p>
```

The above JavaScript code supposed to add paragraph tag not `<pre>` Wondering why its not working for Chrome?

Comment: Formatting is messed up, how do I convert <br> tags to non HTML?

Comment: I did it for you, but you'll have to wait til I'm reviewed. Just enclose in tick marks: \`

Comment: Can you give some more of you code, or maybe a link to the page that you are testing this on?

Answer (score 1):

I made an example of this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MH6kw/2/

..and it seems to work flawlessly.

You have to inspect element on the lower right box to see the results, but I also wrote instructions on there.

I am fairly certain the "content" attribute is only supposed to be used by meta tags, and the obj.content property is only supposed to be used to access meta tags.

What element are you using this on?